# DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fabricjs

**IMPORTANT: Works fine in localhost, but not on a live server. (Godadddy)**

**Issue:**

> Wordpress plugin is giving an error when "preview" button clicked which is not giving the same error on localhost.

**Error:**

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
>   'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

**Line of Error:**

```
var data = canvasObj.toDataURL()
```

Initialisation of `canvasObj`:

```
canvasObj= new fabric.Canvas('wtd_background_image');
```

**Setting image to canvasObj:**

```
  function wtd_load_bg_image( img_url ) 
  {    
    if( img_url )
    {
      var bg_img = new Image(); 
      bg_img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
      bg_img.onload = function()
      {
        canvasObj.setBackgroundImage(bg_img.src, canvasObj.renderAll.bind(canvasObj), {
          originX: 'left',
          originY: 'top',
          left: 0,
          top: 0
        });
      };      
      bg_img.src = img_url;
    }      
  }
```

**Solutions I found online, which are did not work:**

**Modifing htaccess file (Did Not Work!)**

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
            SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**Adding a PHP Header (Did Not Work!)**

adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' to top of the plugin's page as below:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
//header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
get_header();
```

**Adding a crossorigin attribute to image (Did Not Work)**

I added below code to image as you can see above

```
bg_img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
```

**Changin the version of Fabric.js (Works Partially)**

Changing the Fabric.js version from 1.2.0 to different version, this error goes away, but new ones occur. So I don't prefer.

Comment: `setBackgroundImage(bg_img.src ...` will internally create a new image element, without the `crossOrigin` attribute, except if you tell it to do so : `setBackgroundImage(bg_img.src ... top:0,  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'})`; But this would mean you will load your image twice, so don't use this `bg_img`, or alternatively, you can do `bg_img.onload = function(){
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(new fabric.Image(bg_img, {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 1.7.9, and solve other issues.